# Unable to install Java in Firefox

Tags: firefox, java, fedora-17

After installing Java (v.1.7.0_17) via the i386 RPM from Oracle and moving the `libnpjp2.so` file into the `.mozilla/plugins` directory, Firefox does not detect the plugin. From what I have read this should work, but `about:config` and `about:plugins` say nothing about Java. Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT:** Looking in `pluginreg.dat` the `libnpjp2.so` file is listed as `[INVALID]`

Comment: Your life dude.... it's not fun. Your just like me even though something should work the computer decides it hates me and doesn't do it.

Comment: Not that relevant I guess but I might give you an idea: on Windows mozilla puts up a key in HKLocalMachine specific to the java plugin called MozillaPlugins, down to the exact path of that npjp2.dll. After a java update the msi installer messed that up, I got it working on Firefox, but Chrome is still affected. What the installer did was to mess up the path, from bin\plugin2\npjp2.dll to bin\MsiExec\npjp2.dll, which doesn't even exist as a path. Try finding the exact config where libnpjp2.so is defined, if it has a similar setting like in Win. [INVALID] is an indication of that.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. While I did not know the answer right off the bat I did manage to find something that should apply. While this was from fedora-14 it should still apply today. Try following the steps [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Java/FAQ?rd=JavaFAQ).

Edit: If that doesn't work I found another one that is for Fedora 17 [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=280861).

Comment: EasyLife didn't work. Firefox still doesn't recognize the plugin.

Comment: Did you try Fedora ultilities